# Uzbekistan ATMs and Mastercard

Tags: atms, uzbekistan

I have been made aware that very few ATMs in Tashkent accept Mastercard and those that do often run out of cash. I will be needing Uzbek som. I would appreciate advice of the location of any Tashkent airport, bank or hotel ATMs which accept Mastercard reliably 24/7 as I will be arriving at Tashkent airport on a Saturday evening in September.

Comment: Do you want som or USD?

Comment: Which airport will you be arriving at?

Comment: I will be  needing som and arriving at Tashkent on a Saturday evening. I will edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

[Mastercard website](https://www.mastercard.co.uk/en-gb/consumers/get-support/locate-an-atm.html) has an ATM finder.

Put Tashkent in the search box and click find.

There appears to be one in the international airlines terminal at the airport.

Hotel Grand Mir is the closest hotel with one to the city centre (1.46 miles), I'd say it's likely that will be open 24/7.

There's other hotels in the search results though and on street ATMs (also likely to be available 24/7).

Comment: Does the ATM finder tell which currency is dispensed? For some reason, when I try to search it, I only get a blank box instead of a list of ATMs.

Comment: Thank you. The link, oddly, will not work on my Win10 PC but did on my android phone. Very helpful.

Comment: @MichaelHampton no it doesn't... Alan also says it didn't work on his Windows 10 PC but did on his Android, worked on my Mac with Chrome. Website must have some compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2):

From when I went in 2011, it's TOUGH to find one. Things have hopefully improved, but I found ATMs (two) - both Mastercard and Visa - at the Grand Mir hotel. They also have a nice cafe (albeit expensive).

It's also a convenient place to hide while waiting for your Tajikistan visa (close to the embassy) and you're without passport.

Comment: Thank you. Based on the answers here I was able to focus my searches. It appears the Grand Mir ATM is an Asaka Bank ATM. That bank has half a dozen dotted around the city. I will arrange for a driver to pick me up at the airport and take me to accommodation via the Grand Mir but I will also arrange some US$ as my emergency backup.